# High performance unique timestamp id for multiple threads in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, performance, haskell, uniqueidentifier

I have multiple threads processing events. I want to assign a nanosecond timestamp to each event. It must be a unique id, though. So, in the odd case that two events arrive such that they would be assigned the same timestamp, I want one of them to be incremented by one nanosecond. Given that the real precision is not at the nanosecond level, that's ok as far as the time stamp nature of the system.

In one thread, this is a trivial problem. But across multiple threads, it gets more challenging. Performance is absolutely critical so the idea of naively synchronizing on a typical id generator type of thing seems like it would block far too much.

Is there some approach that solves this with minimal or no locking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `atomicModifyIORef` to implement an atomic counter.  With GHC, it's implemented using atomic operations, not locks.

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

counter :: IO Int
counter = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef 0

getUnique :: IO Int
getUnique = atomicModifyIORef counter $ \x -> let y = x + 1 in (y, y)
```

Comment: @ehird: Please do not make nontrivial changes to my post, post a comment instead if you have something to add.

Comment: Sorry, I felt the change I was making was trivial enough but then saw an additional two errors before saving. Currently, `getUnique` always returns `⊥`, and `counter` could be inlined into other expressions, duplicating the variable and breaking the code. Additionally, if both these were fixed, then `getUnique` would have a space leak caused by thunks building up on successive executions. (BTW, the standard `Data.Unique` module actually provides this API already.)

Comment: @ehird: That's exactly the kind of information I wanted to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not separate the concerns of timestamping and unique ID generation? For example, there's the standard module [`Data.Unique`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Unique.html), which provides a global supply of unique values in `IO` and should be fast enough for most purposes. Or, if you need something fancier, the [concurrent-supply](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-supply) package offers a high-performance, concurrent unique ID supply with a pure interface.

That said, you could probably use the [POSIX monotonic clock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_226) for this purpose, using e.g. the [clock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clock) package:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified System.Posix.Clock as Clock

main :: IO ()
main = replicateM_ 100 $ do
  time <- Clock.getTime Clock.Monotonic
  print (Clock.sec time, Clock.nsec time)
```

Comment: @augustss: The POSIX monotonic clock? I'm not sure. If it isn't fast enough, that's another good reason to decouple timestamping and ID generation.

Comment: @ehird will a Unique ID in the was created at time b in all cases have a higher value than a Unique ID that was created at time a (earlier)?

Comment: @JFritsch: `Unique` is based on an `Integer` increased atomically, so yes. (Although technically you can only get an `Int` out of that, so only the `Eq` and `Ord` instances can distinguish pre- and post-wrap-around values, but on a 64-bit machine that won't be a problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Could you use two pieces of information as the unique id? If so, give each thread a unique id and record for each event the nanosecond timestamp and the id of the thread that assigns the timestamp. Then the problem reduces to whatever you would have done in the single threaded case to guarantee the uniqueness of the timestamps. And with no synchronisation at all after initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

In C based languages, we'd normally accomplish this using an atomic counter -- no lock is required. If you want a timestamp too, that would be a separate value. I'm not sure about Haskell because I don't write with it (as interesting as it sounds).

Answer (score 0):

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/greg-client maybe?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.